# Applying the Frobenius method to $x^2 y'' - 2x y' - 10y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Here is the equation:

$$x^2 y'' - 2x y' - 10y = 0 \tag{E}$$

We want to find, using the method of Frobenius, a solution in the neighbourhood of $0$, which is here a regular-singular point.

Indicial equation: $\lambda^2 - 3\lambda - 10 = 0$

Solutions: $\lambda_1 = 5$ and $\lambda_2 = -2$. As $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 = 7 \in \mathbb N$, we have by the theorem that there are two linearly independent solutions of the form:

$$y_1(x) = x^5 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^{n+5}$$

and

$$y_2(x) = x^3 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n x^n + k y_1(x) \ln(x)$$

Let's find $\{a_n\}_{n = 0}^\infty$.

We have:

$$y_1 ' = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n+5)a_n x^{n+4} $$

$$y_1 '' = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n+4)(n+5)a_n x^{n + 3}$$

Replacing in $(E)$, we obtain:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n^2 + 7n)a_n x^{n+5} = 0$$

And this gives:

$$a_n = 0, \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb N$$

So, $y_1(x) = 0$. In turn, this gives $y_2(x) = 0$ as well.

So we did not obtain any non-trivial solutions.

> What should be done in this case? How do we solve an equation of this type if it's not solvable using the method of Frobenius? Did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: aren't $y = x^5$ and $y = \frac1{x^2}$ solutions of the cauchy equation $x^2y'' - 2xy' - 10y = 0?$ why do you anything more?

Comment: @abel I did notice that. But this is a part of an exercise which requires using the method of Frobenius to solve the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtained $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n^2 + 7n)a_n x^{n+5} = 0$ which is correct.

So, it is necessary that $a_n=0$ except in case of $(n^2+7n)=0$ which roots are $n=0$ and $n=-7$.

The two remaining terms are $a_0 x^{0+5}$ and $a_{-7}x^{-7+5}$

Changing the symbols of coefficients, the general solution of the ODE is :
$$y(x)=c_1x^5+c_2 x^{-2}$$